# Is it restful to have request body with optional parameters that will be required for some calls

Tags: rest, api, restful-architecture

I want to build a rest api for payments but the request body will have parameters based on the payment type. I am not sure as to whether it is restful to have optional parameters that will be required for some payment types. Here is the example endpoint details,

POST /clients/{id}/payments/{type}

```
{
    amount: integer,
    card_details: {
        number: string,
        expiry: string
    },
    bank_details: {
        bsb: string,
        account_number: string
    },
    reference: string
}
```

The bank_details and card_details are not required all the time, however if the payment type is credit card it would require card details and if the type is bank deposit then bank details are required.
I feel this approach is not ideal. Is there a better way to implement this or is it fine to go with this approach?
Hope I have framed the question with all the details required. I would really appreciate your suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The `bank_details` and `card_details` are not required all the time, however if the payment type is credit card it would require `card_details` and if the type is bank deposit then `bank_details` are required.

On my understanding, your application allows the client to create different resources with different representations. And that's just fine. According to the [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231), the [`POST`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.3) method requests that the target resource process the representation enclosed in the request according to the resource's own specific semantics.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. That was helpful :)